# Is there a way to turn off messages in elfinder?

Tags: elfinder

I'd like to get rid of the elfinder messages.  It's a good ui - so when a user makes a folder, they don't need a big green box that says "folder created successfully".  So many config options ... anybody know how to disable all of the notification boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.elfinder-toast .toast-success {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```